# How to unpack a either::Either by the contained type

Tags: rust, serde

Can I unpack a [either::Either](https://docs.rs/either/latest/either/) by the contained type, not by side?

Say I have a `Either<u8, f32>`, and want to either get `None` or a value with the desired type, without knowing with side the value is in.

I've tried doing it with macros like this:

```rust
/// Unpack a 2 option item
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! unpack_dual {
    ( $item: expr, $item_t: ty ) => {
        match $item.inner {
            either::Either<$item_t, _> => {
                if let either::Right(item) => $item.inner {
                    Some(item)
                } else {
                    None
                }
            }
        },
        either::Either<_, $item_t> => {
            if let either::Left(item) = $item.inner {
                Some(item)
            } else {
                None
            }
        }
    };
}
```

where you pass the value and the desired type, but It doesn't work because you can't match on the `Either` shape.

This is for ease of use with a configuration file parser where there are fields that may be one of 2 things it uses `Either`.

Like in this example struct, using `structstruck` for nesting and `serde` for deserialization.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use either::Either;

extern crate structstruck;

use serde::{Deserialize};
use serde_yaml as yaml;

structstruck::strike! {
    #[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
    struct Example {
        pub dual_field: HashMap<String,
                              #[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
                              #[serde(transparent)]
                              pub struct TypeAOrTypeB {
                                  #[serde(with = "either::serde_untagged")]
                                  pub inner:
                                  Either<#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
                                         pub struct TypeA {
                                             // -- snip --
                                         },
                                         #[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
                                         pub struct TypeA {
                                             // -- snip --
                                         }>>
                              }
   // -- snip ---
}
```

Comment: There's no way to do this, because `Either` can have the same type on both sides, and Rust has no way of limiting implementations to only the case where those types are different.

Comment: Do you need the solution to be generic or for specific type?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I prefer it would be generic, because on the original application this question came from there are many instances like this, where either is applied to get one of 2 options, and writing specific code for each case would be tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I can come up with that uses only `std` is via `Any` which restricts this approach to types that are `'static`.

```
use either::Either::{self, *};
use std::any::Any;

fn unpack_dual<L: 'static, R: 'static, T: 'static>(e: &Either<L, R>) -> Option<&T> {
    let e: Either<&dyn Any, &dyn Any> = e.as_ref().either(|l| Left(l as &dyn Any), |r| Right(r as &dyn Any));
    e.either(|l| l.downcast_ref::<T>(), |r| r.downcast_ref::<T>())
}


fn main() {
    let e: Either<u8, f32> = Right(3.1415);
    let maybe_u8: Option<&u8> = unpack_dual(&e);
    let maybe_f32: Option<&f32> = unpack_dual(&e);
    let probably_not_string: Option<&String> = unpack_dual(&e);

    assert_eq!(maybe_u8, None);
    assert_eq!(maybe_f32, Some(&3.1415));
    assert_eq!(probably_not_string, None);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I improve this somehow with a macro? I thought of using a `procmacro` for this, but I don't understand it well enough to use it.

Comment: I've written proc macros before so I understand them ok, but even then I can't think of a better way although there very well might be one. Your doing type introspection _at runtime_ here, so I'm not sure how proc macros would help. But then, I'm also not 100% sure how exactly you want to end up calling this. If you could whip up a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) where you illustrate how you'd end up actually using the function, I could take another look at it.

Comment: I did [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c51057d1eb5cca434c98fbe8587a00ad) but the used version of Either, doesn't has `serde_untagged`. Testing the function in context with the original problem, it does exactly what I wanted. The macro idea was just a guess, maybe by implementing a trait which matches the type to the desired side.